# parse and map json using postman

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

```
@Controller
public class StudentRegistrationController {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value="/register/reg")
@ResponseBody
StudentRegistrationReply registerStudent(@RequestBody Student student) {
    System.out.println("In registerStudent");
    StudentRegistrationReply stdregreply = new StudentRegistrationReply();           

    StudentRegistration.getInstance().add(student);

    //We are setting the below value just to reply a message back to the caller
    stdregreply.setId(student.getId());
    stdregreply.setName(student.getName());
    stdregreply.setAge(student.getAge());
    stdregreply.setRegistrationNumber(student.getRegistrationNumber());
    stdregreply.setPayment_detailsList(student.getPayment_detailsList());
    stdregreply.setRegistrationStatus("Successful");

    daocontroller.setStudentRegistration(stdregreply);
    return stdregreply;

}

}
```

trying to map the postman request to but getting null

json is like

```
{ 
    "id": 300,
    "name": "kukri",
    "age": 26,
    "registrationNumber": "54326",
    "Student_payment_details":
    {
      "pay": 50000,
      "date": "23061994",
      "phcounter": "SKB"
    }

}
```

**Java classes**

```
public class Student {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String registrationNumber;
    private Student_payment_details payment_detailsList; //getter and setter
}
```

Comment: So you have this method, and you are trying to receive a POST request from Postman?

Comment: for your ref: https://github.com/dineshbhagat/spring-boot-web-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/controller/ArticleCommentController.java

Comment: Can you share the Student class? I'm not quite sure that `Student_payment_details`  follows the standard var name convention.

Comment: public class Student {
 private int id;
 private String name;
 private int age;
 private String registrationNumber;
 private Student_payment_details payment_detailsList;
          //getter and setter 
}

Comment: @juanlumn actually there is 2 bean class is there ,it depend upon my json data what i am getting from postman response which map to both the classes     { 
    "id": 300,
    "name": "kukri",
    "age": 26,
    "registrationNumber": "54326",
    "Student_payment_details":
    {
      "pay": 50000,
      "date": "23061994",
      "phcounter": "SKB"
    }
}

Comment: @ngueno yes ,i want to get the data from postman json request and map to my bean classes, actully i am getting the all the data except "Student_payment_details"

Comment: show this class `private Student_payment_details` and also `private Student_payment_details payment_detailsList` reference name should match to json key `"Student_payment_details"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Using Lombok as my getter/setters, you can ignore it and write your own getters/setters
2. There is issue with the body of your request, you should pass key in json as java variable name, you are passing `Student_payment_details` instead of `payment_detailsList`
3. Getters and Setters should be with respect to your variable name.

Request url:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8080/register/reg \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d '{
  "id": 300,
  "name": "kukri",
  "age": 26,
  "registrationNumber": "54326",
  "payment_detailsList": {
    "pay": 50000,
    "date": "23061994",
    "phcounter": "SKB"
  }
}'
```

Java Dtos:

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Student_payment_details {
    int pay;
    String date;
    String phcounter;
}

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Student {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String registrationNumber;
    private Student_payment_details payment_detailsList; //getter and setter
}
```

Following image shows the content of a student variable populated inside the controller

[image]

Note:
I do not know your use case but as a general suggestion, please follow 1 type of naming convention,`snake_case` or `camelCase`.
In java mostly used is `camelCase`.
Also naming of the variable should be similar to the class type,
here variable payment_detailsList is of type `Student_payment_details` which leads to confusion, if you want JSON variable name to be different then you can use as

```
 @JsonProperty("payment_detailsList")
 private Student_payment_details student_payment_details;
```

Comment: sorry sir @dkb for naming conventions ,and thanks for for solution , but still its not working . can you please check at https://github.com/shashikantsahu67/spring-boot-rest/blob/master/jsontestrequest.zip

Comment: can you try with above DTOs and curl request, and check, should work fine.

Comment: yeah i did it but still i am getting null for student_payment_details

Comment: There are multiple issues with DTOs, 1. If you are specifying parameterized constructor then java will not create a default constructor, 2. You are using Lombok's @data annotations, you should not add explicit getters/setters. 3. Just add above dtos as it is. and import curl request in postman., 4. You need to enable annotation processing from ide to make use of lombok.

Comment: got it ,but if i'll remove the getter and setter then i need to change my program structure ,i dont how to set the values ,how lombok works , i need to read it out first . and thanks for all this @dkb